# Does titration usually always involve neutralization?

Tags: aqueous-solution, stoichiometry, titration

I've been doing titration exercises that involve figuring out the molarity of an unknown solution when you know the molarity of another (so like knowing the molarity of solution A but figuring out the molarity of solution B), and it usually always involves neutralization. Is it common that titration exercises involve neutralization?

Comment: It is common, but other types of reactions (redox, etc.) are common as well.

Comment: A lot of titrations are acid-base in nature, but not all of them are. Some are redox, like permanganate with iron(II). Some are precipitation titrations (e.g. Mohr's method) and some are complexometric titrations (e.g. with EDTA). Some are not even monitored with a colour change, for example you can measure the conductivity of the solution (conductometric titration). It is quite common, but do not think that it is the only thing.

Comment: As you can see from the other comments, neutralization strongly implies an acid-base reaction in chemistry but there are other types of reactions which can be used in a quantitative analysis titration. A reaction could be  redox. You could also do a titration that involves creating a precipitate, or a reaction that involves a substance partitioning between two liquid phases. So there are a lot of different kinds of titrations in quantitative chemistry.

Comment: To give you some examples of a non-neutralization titration reactions, I have actually titrated $\ce{H2O2}$ using yeast catalase and on another occasion $\ce{H2O2}$ using $\ce{KMnO4}$.

Answer (score 6):

While neutralization of an acid (or a base) is a frequent example of titration, titration is more general. IUPAC's gold book [mentions](http://goldbook.iupac.org/T06387.html)  "Also contains definitions of: acidimetric titration, acid–base titration, alkalimetric titration, chelatometric titration, complexometric titration, coulometric titration, equivalence point, precipitation titration" right in the beginning.  Even the emblematic glass buret is not a must, as publications like [My Dear Buret, Your Time Has Indeed Come!](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jchemed.5b00773) (Journal of Chemical Education) showcase.